# Pandas, how to make matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have a question about pandas and if someone could help me, I would be grateful for that very much.

I have a dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'Name': ['A', 'B','A','A']})
df1
```

I want to do groupby for this.

```
x=df1.groupby("Name").size()
x
```

I also have another dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame( {'Name2': ['Jon',Maria','Maria','Mike','Mike','Mike']})
df2
```

For this one, I do groupby as well.
    y= df2.groupby("Name2").size()

And then I want to make matrix whose column is x and row is y, and want to multiply the values.
I want the matrix like this.

```
     Jon  Maria     Mike
A    3       6         9
B    1       2         3
```

If you could tell me how to do that, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perform a dot product:

```
x.to_frame().dot(y.to_frame().T)

Name2  Jon  Maria  Mike
Name                   
A        3      6     9
B        1      2     3
```

---

If you want to remove the axis labels, use `rename_axis`:

```
x.to_frame().dot(y.to_frame().T)\
      .rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, 1)

   Jon  Maria  Mike
A    3      6     9
B    1      2     3
```

Alternatively, assign in-place:

```
v = x.to_frame().dot(y.to_frame().T)
v.index.name = v.columns.name = None

v

   Jon  Maria  Mike
A    3      6     9
B    1      2     3
```

Comment: @MaxU Aww, come on! We had the same idea :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  You guys are awesome!!

Comment: @Tom_Hanks don’t forget to accept an answer if it solved your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [35]: (pd.DataFrame(y[:,None].dot(x[:,None].T).T, columns=y.index, index=x.index)
            .rename_axis(None)
            .rename_axis(None,1))
Out[35]:
   Jon  Maria  Mike
A    3      6     9
B    1      2     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Or we can using `np.multiply.outer`

```
pd.DataFrame(np.multiply.outer(x.values,y.values),columns=y.index,index=x.index)
Out[344]: 
Name2  Jon  Maria  Mike
Name                   
A        3      6     9
B        1      2     3
```

Comment: This should be slightly better: `pd.DataFrame(np.outer(x, y), index=x.index, columns=y.index)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yeah :-) PS: your is the best :-)